# How to play .ism/manifest file?

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I am developing the iOS app and wanted to play below file using Xamarin, but did not get any solution to play `.ism`/`manifest` file.

https://amssamples.streaming.mediaservices.windows.net/91492735-c523-432b-ba01-faba6c2206a2/AzureMediaServicesPromo.ism/manifest

I am using below code to play the audio file.

```
AVPlayer player = new AVPlayer ();
        var playerItem = (url != null) ? new AVPlayerItem(url) : null;
        player.ReplaceCurrentItemWithPlayerItem (playerItem);
        player.Play()
```

How to play this file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Your URL is missing `(format=m3u8-aapl)`

2) Do not let your `AVPlayer` go out of scope, hold a reference to it at the `UIViewController` level.

If you create an iOS project via the single view template, replace the `ViewDidLoad` method in the `ViewController` class with the following and your "audio" will play.

FYI: The URL is actually providing video also...

```
AVPlayer player;
public override void ViewDidLoad()
{
    base.ViewDidLoad();
    var url = new NSUrl("https://amssamples.streaming.mediaservices.windows.net/91492735-c523-432b-ba01-faba6c2206a2/AzureMediaServicesPromo.ism/manifest(format=m3u8-aapl)");
    player = new AVPlayer();
    player.ReplaceCurrentItemWithPlayerItem(new AVPlayerItem(url));
    player.Play();                
}
```

Comment: one more thing, if you could help me, my files requires tocken authentication, could you please let me know how can i pass the tocken authentication to access the file?

Comment: my file is AES encrypted

Comment: @RahulSomwanshi You will need to implement `AVAssetResourceLoaderDelegate` to apply to an `AVAssetResourceLoader` to provide your token.