# Xamarin : how to play .ism/manifest file in Xamarin cross platform app

Tags: azure, xamarin, xamarin.forms, cross-platform, azure-media-services

I am developing the Xamarin cross-platform app and wanted to play below file using Xamarin, but did not get any solution to play .ism/manifest file.

https://amssamples.streaming.mediaservices.windows.net/91492735-c523-432b-ba01-faba6c2206a2/AzureMediaServicesPromo.ism/manifest

Comment: Your url isn't accessible, showing _403 - Forbidden_.

Comment: https://4027149f79204db7aa42c89da99695cb.azureedge.net/e987b30c-671a-4984-b754-7ea9acd92c87/DIY_ Fairy Glow Jars.ism/manifest

Comment: Unfortunately! this link too not working anyway. It would be better to ask question in proper way so that people can understand what you are asking. Avoid to give links in question unless it is necessary.

Comment: That ism/manifest file is playing in azure media player. But that is not playing on google. I have to write the code in Xamarin that, ism/manifest file should play.

Comment: You can check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44146616/xamarin-how-to-play-ism-manifest-file-in-ios & https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-use-a-simple-adaptive-streaming-uri-in-uwp-with-xaml-and-c-sharp/

Comment: https://blog.xamarin.com/play-audio-and-video-with-the-mediamanager-plugin-for-xamarin/

Comment: @SushiHangover In that document, they have taken  .mp4 files. But I have ism/manifest files.

Comment: @CGPA6.4 In that documentation, they have considered native ios and uwp.I want for crossplatform means common for all android,ios and uwp.

Comment: @Shilpa - Writing platform specific code not a bad idea provided it should work. If you are unable to do in shared project. From above link/threads try creating depencency service.  Refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53153603/how-do-you-create-on-xamarin-a-function-that-does-something-differently-dependin/